# ERROR java: cannot find symbol when building with JHipster

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

Im following JHipster tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=410&v=uQqlO3IGpTU&feature=emb_title

Im using java 11 as recommended. Why am I gettin this ERROR?

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

Error:(8, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Email
  location: package javax.validation.constraints
Error:(9, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotBlank
  location: package javax.validation.constraints
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message appears to be referring to something that the compiler doesn't understand. Check if there is some dependency missing, for example a jar containing the classes that you need must be added to the build path of your project.

Comment: deleted the whole project. generated a new one using java 11. boom done